# Quem já é moderador no site precisa se candidatar as eleições?

Tags: debate, eleição

Nas eleições vi que alguns usuários que já são moderadores estão concorrendo para as vagas.

Então significa que depois da eleição só teremos 3 moderadores? Ou os que já eram continuam e ganhamos mais três moderadores?

Answer (score 9):

Ao final da eleição, teremos 3 moderadores eleitos pela comunidade.

Os atuais (@bfavaretto e @utluiz) foram escolhidos pela SE e não pela comunidade na época do beta.
Então, caso eles não tivessem se candidatado, eles perderiam o diamante de moderador.

Comment: Apenas se candidatar novamente não é o suficiente para manter o diamante, é necessário ser eleito :) Isso tem grandes chances de acontecer, mas é bom deixar clara a distinção.